# SQL How to Set Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create 3 tables which look like this

student(**sid: CHAR(12)**, sname: VARCHAR(50), bdate: DATE, address: VARCHAR(50), scity: VARCHAR(20), year: CHAR(20), gpa: FLOAT)

company(**cid: CHAR(8)**, cname: VARCHAR(20))

apply(**sid: CHAR(12)**, **cid: CHAR(8)**)

(Bolded attributes are primary keys)

But I'm not sure how to set the foreign keys since for instance **cid** of apply table is both primary key in apply table and company table ( which has the same situation for **sid** between apply table and student table). Thanks for any help.

These are the codes for creating tables:

```
myQuery = "CREATE TABLE student "
                + "(sid CHAR(12), sname VARCHAR(50), "
                + "bdate DATE, address VARCHAR(50), "
                + "scity VARCHAR(20), year CHAR(20), "
                + "gpa FLOAT) ENGINE=InnoDB;";
 myQuery = "CREATE TABLE company "
                + "(cid CHAR(8), cname VARCHAR(20), quota CHAR(8))ENGINE=InnoDB;";
myQuery = "CREATE TABLE apply "
                + "(sid CHAR(12), cid CHAR(8)) ENGINE=InnoDB;";
```

Comment: you can have a primary key also be a foreign key.

Comment: the cid in the apply table is the FK, the cid in the company table is the PK

Comment: Use innodb type tables and your problems will be solved user joins to get data

Comment: Craete primary or unique keys: company(cid) and apply(sid), then add foreign keys, see example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086210/mysql-error-on-create-table-for-many-to-many-relationship/10086399#10086399

Comment: @raheelshan I am already using InnoDB tables but foreign keys should be specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `apply` table is a many-to-many join between `student` and `company`.

In that case, you'd want to set `student` and `company` like you have (though posting the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE student` may get you more helpful answers). So for the apply table, you want two foreign keys: one on `sid` which references `student.sid`, and one on `cid` which references `company.cid`. Maybe something like:

```
ALTER TABLE apply ADD CONSTRAINT sid FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student(sid);
ALTER TABLE apply ADD CONSTRAINT cid FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES copmany(cid);
```

Edit: Based on your table creation, you're not setting the primary keys either. Add a `PRIMARY KEY` identifier to any column you wish to be a primary key.

Comment: Can alter table integrate to innodb type of tables? since I'm using InnoDB engine

Comment: Yes. They work on all engines. You'll want to use InnoDB if you're working with Foreign Keys.

Comment: I added PRIMARY KEY identifier with primary values of relevant table on table creation. Also added alter table statements  that you provided after all table created. Now how can I check this works or not.(btw it compiles and creates all tables and inserts datas without any error or exception)

Comment: A FK requires that the data being inserted exists in the destination table. So Try adding a reference to a company that's not in the company table. It should fail.

Answer (score 0):

i the apply table set both sid and cid as foreignkeys..this table is called a junction table here the primary key is a composite primary key both sid and cid together.
appply table foreign keys are SID and CID
apply table primary key is (sid,cid) composite primary key.
Each company can have any number of students..
Each student can be part of any number of companies
but one combination wont repeat.